# SQLAlchemy 1:1 mapping

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using python and SQLAlchemy 2.0 with PostgreSQL, I am trying to create a simple one to one mapping between two tables. The code is:

```
class Base(orm.DeclarativeBase): 
    pk: orm.Mapped[uuid.UUID] = orm.mapped_column(
    primary_key=True,
    default=uuid.uuid4,
    )


class AAA(Base):
    __tablename__ = "aaa"

    name: orm.Mapped[str]
    # 1:1 mapping with BBB 
    linked_bbb: orm.Mapped["BBB"] = relationship(back_populates="linked_aaa", lazy="selectin")


class BBB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bbb"

    name: orm.Mapped[str]

    # 1:1 mapping with AAA 
    linked_aaa: orm.Mapped["AAA"] = relationship(back_populates="linked_bbb", lazy="selectin")
```

The code runs and produces this schema in Postgres:

```
my_db=> \d aaa
                     Table "public.aaa"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 name   | character varying |           | not null | 
 pk     | uuid              |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "aaa_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pk)

my_db=> \d bbb
                     Table "public.bbb"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 name   | character varying |           | not null | 
 pk     | uuid              |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "bbb_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pk)
```

I was expecting that each table would have a column linking it back to the other. What am I missing?

Comment: Relationships exist solely in the Python layer.You need to declare the foreign keys in the model to make the link in the database layer (see [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one)).

Comment: The Postgres schema also doesn't have the `name` columns.

Comment: Oh true, the name columns are missing. I created this example from a much larger bit of code, that does make the other columns. I didn't notice this had that issue since I was focused on the links.

Comment: Oh I see me error with the name field, I'll correct the question.

Comment: Okay @snakecharmerb I see... I'm still figuring out how this all works. If I need to create a column for the primark key myself, what does the relationship() method do?

Comment: Relationships (1) simplify working with related models in an object-oriented way, for example you can get a user's email addresses with `user.emails` rather than manually querying the emails table for foriegn keys for the user (2) allow expression of more complex relationships than relational dbs permit, for example you could have a relationship that includes all of a user's email addresses that end in `gmail.com`.